# Need to Commit my Project from local to SVN Repository (first time)

Tags: svn

I have created a project on my local machine, and now i want to place it on SVN repository  so that my colleagues who all working on same project can access the code.

I know how to check in an Existing code in SVN , but since our project is not exist in SVN repository i am not finding any proper way to do that.

Please assist me on this issue.

Comment: Couldn't you have found this out by searching. Please don't use StackOverflow as an alternative to Google.

Comment: Hi Tom, 
I tried searching for my problem but i didn't get any proper way as a solution.
My intention was not to use StackOverflow as an alternative of any.

Comment: I don't believe you. Google "add project to svn" - the 7th result yields [the appropriate page in the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html).

You may want to to create a directory first in the repository for your project using [svn mkdir](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html) then run the import

See the examples in links above.

Comment: Do you intentionally provide links to outdated/nightly SVNBook? It's not recommended.

[[
This text is a work in progress—highly subject to change—and may not accurately describe any released version of the Apache™ Subversion® software. Bookmarking or otherwise referring others to this page is probably not such a smart idea. Please visit http://www.svnbook.com/ for stable versions of this book.
]]

Comment: @bahrep No this was not my intention, those were just the first results google came up with. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a command line tool or a GUI tool such as TortoiseSVN?

What you need to do is add the files to the repository and then commit the changes. How you do this depends on the tools you are using.

Comment: As of Now i am using GUI tool TortoiseSVN.
Is it something like, i need to go by right clikcing on my project from workspace and then proceed with SVN Checkout Option ?

Answer (score 0):

http://nimblepros.com/what-we-say/newsletters/agile-perspectives-issue-4/setting-up-visualsvn-server.aspx it might be helpful for you..